# Laravel Livewire 3.0 multiple checkbox not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm currently experimenting with Livewire 3.0, and I've encountered an issue with checkboxes arrays as input. When I submit the form, I'm receiving an empty array on the component. Can anyone help me identify what might be missing in my implementation? Thanks in advance!

I have a Livewire component that includes a form with multiple checkboxes. These checkboxes are intended to create an array of selected options when submitted. However, upon form submission, the component receives an empty array instead of the expected values.

Any guidance or insight into the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again!

Here is my component :

```
<?php 
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class SlotComponent extends Component
{
    public $slots = [];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.slot-component');
    }
    
    public function save()
    {
       // echo implode(',',$this->slots);
        logger(json_encode($this->slots));
    }
}
```

```
<div class="flex justify-center items-center">
    <div class="w-full mx-auto py-4">
        <form action="#" method="POST" wire:submit="save">
            <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto p-6 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl animate-fade-in-down">
                <h1 class="text-3xl font-semibold mb-6 text-center">{{ __('Select Seats') }}</h1>
                <!-- Seat Map Container -->
                <div class="grid grid-cols-20 gap-6 shadow-md bg-white rounded-lg p-4 animate-fade-in-up">
                    <!-- Generate Seats -->
                    @for ($row = 1; $row <= 10; $row++)
                        <div class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap">
                            @foreach( range('A', 'T') as $element)
                                <div class="p-0.5">
                                    <input wire:modal='slots' type="checkbox" id="seat-{{ $row }}{{ $loop->iteration }}" class="absolute opacity-0 w-full h-full cursor-pointer hidden peer" value="{{ $element }}{{ $row }}">
                                    <label for="seat-{{ $row }}{{ $loop->iteration }}" class="h-10 w-10 relative p-2 border-green-400 border rounded-md transform hover:scale-125 hover:bg-green-400 hover:border-white transition-transform flex justify-center items-center peer-checked:bg-green-400 cursor-pointer">
                                        {{ $element }}{{ $row }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    @endfor
                </div>
                <!-- Number of Tickets Input -->
                <div class="mt-6">
                    <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">{{ __('Selected Tickets') }} : {{ count($slots) }}</label>
                </div>
        
                <!-- Book Button -->
                <div class="mt-6 text-center">
                    <button class="bg-pink-600 text-white px-6 py-3 rounded-md hover:bg-pink-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-pink-300 focus:ring-opacity-50" type="submit">
                        {{ __('Book Tickets') }}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your markup, `wire:modal` should be `wire:model`.

Comment: @Qirel Oh!! Thanks a lot man, I have no words to say.